# Cannot access variable to save in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I´m doing an extension method where I want to my variable `image` equals to name of my pic

Extension Method:

```
 public async Task<string> CreateNewSlider(Slider slider, HttpPostedFileBase file) // file always return null
    {
        string pic = null;
        if (file != null)
        {
            pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider"), pic);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
            }
        }
        try
        {
            var createnewslider = new Slider
            {
                Alt = slider.Alt,
                CreationDate = slider.CreationDate,
                Description = slider.Description,
                IsVisible = slider.IsVisible,
                Order = slider.Order,
                Subtitle = slider.Subtitle,
                Title = slider.Title,
                VideoLink = slider.VideoLink,
                Image = pic
            };
            db.SlidersList.Add(createnewslider);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return "Slider Photo " + file + "has been created successfull";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.InnerException.Message + "Contact to administrator";
        }

    }
```

How can I do to access to my variable `pic` and finally post into my model

Note: "Image variable is type string"

----------------------Edit----------------------

I have a problem trying to create new slider, I want to create it and store image into image variable on database

Model:

```
public class Slider
{
    public int SliderId { get; set; }
    public int MainPageId { get; set; }
    public MainPage MainPage { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }
    public string VideoLink { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

Create View:

```
@model xxx.Models.Slider

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Slider</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Order, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subtitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subtitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subtitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Slider", FormMethod.Post,
                        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {
            <label for="file">Subir imágen:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
           }
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoLink, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VideoLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsVisible, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsVisible)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsVisible, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

In extension Method it pass to catch exception and return it

I use debug mode, and file variable is always null but I don't know why

Comment: where are you doing the `Extension Method`...? I do not see the first param in your method qualified with `this`

Comment: Write code of model inside file condition you have checked otherwise declare pic variable above file condition.

Comment: I do it, there is my model and View @AkramKhan, now it pass to exception  reference and I don't know why

Comment: and `pic` variable always return `""` @AkramKhan

Comment: @MethodMan I think OP means *action* method.

Comment: I edit it, I dont know how to do snnipet @GertArnold

Comment: Ok, Its already now @GertArnold

Comment: Use enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form if you are sending image.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `pic` isn't available in the scope of your `createnewslider` object. Simply declare the `pic` variable outside the if statement:

```
string pic = string.Empty;

if (file != null) {
    pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider"), pic);
    file.SaveAs(path);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
        byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
    }
}
var createnewslider = new Slider
{
    Alt = slider.Alt,
    CreationDate = slider.CreationDate,
    Description = slider.Description,
    IsVisible = slider.IsVisible,
    Order = slider.Order,
    Subtitle = slider.Subtitle,
    Title = slider.Title,
    VideoLink = slider.VideoLink,
    Image = pic
};
```

And check the contents before mapping to `Image`.

Comment: I do it, but my submit don't save in database

Comment: I upload model, extension method and View

Answer (score 0):

Define it in the same scope as the constructor so that the constructor will have access to it.

```
public async Task<string> CreateNewSlider(Slider slider, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string pic = null;
    if (file != null)
    {
        pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                               HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider"), pic);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
    var createnewslider = new Slider
    {
        Alt = slider.Alt,
        CreationDate = slider.CreationDate,
        Description = slider.Description,
        IsVisible = slider.IsVisible,
        Order = slider.Order,
        Subtitle = slider.Subtitle,
        Title = slider.Title,
        VideoLink = slider.VideoLink,
        Image = pic // I can´t access to pic variable 

    };
    db.SlidersList.Add(createnewslider);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return "Slider Photo " + file + "has been created";

}
```